# DB2 SQL Aggregation

Tags: sql, db2

I have a set of records in a DB2 database and I need to present a report in which all the fields for business done by users are provided for all users. All the different MGD_TYPE have been summarized for all users. How can I do this using SQL?

```
USER_ID         MGD_TYPE                 MTHLY_AMT            EFF_DATE
1222            FX                       332.21              06/23/10
3333            REAL_ESTATE              2221.03             06/23/10
1222            MERGERS                 1882.43              02/03/12
3333            PORTFOLIO                721.44              01/22/15


USER            FX_AMT          REAL_EST_AMT         MERGERS_AMT         PORTFOLIO_AMT  
1222            332.21           0.0                    1882.43          0.0
3333            0.0             2221.03                 0.0              721.44
```

Comment: Possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784095/convert-rows-into-column-in-db2
I suggest to search for similar questions and useful answers before you post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic PIVOT query:

```
SELECT USER_ID,
  SUM( CASE MGD_TYPE WHEN 'FX'          THEN MTHLY_AMT END ) As FX_AMT,
  SUM( CASE MGD_TYPE WHEN 'REAL_ESTATE' THEN MTHLY_AMT END ) As REAL_EST_AMT,
  SUM( CASE MGD_TYPE WHEN 'MERGERS'     THEN MTHLY_AMT END ) As MERGERS_AMT,
  SUM( CASE MGD_TYPE WHEN 'PORTFOLIO'   THEN MTHLY_AMT END ) As PORTFOLIO_AMT
FROM table
GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much